# groups acess right login admin and login user probleme

Tags: odoo

**security.xml**

```
<record id="group_gi_admin" model="res.groups">
        <field name="name">admin</field>
        <field name="category_id" ref="module_category_gi"/>
    </record>

    <record id="group_gi_etudiant" model="res.groups">
        <field name="name">etudiant</field>
        <field name="category_id" ref="module_category_gi"/>
    </record>
```

**ir.model.access.csv**

```
access_gi_etudiant_admin,access.gi.etudiant.admin,model_gi_etudiant,group_gi_admin,1,1,1,1

access_gi_professeur_admin,access.gi.professeur.admin,model_gi_professeur,group_gi_admin,1,1,1,1

access_gi_module_admin,access.gi.module.admin,model_gi_module,group_gi_admin,1,1,1,1

access_gi_specialite_admin,access.gi.specialite.admin,model_gi_specialite,group_gi_admin,1,1,1,1

access_gi_classroom_etudiant,access.gi.classroom.etudiant,model_gi_classroom,group_gi_etudiant,1,0,0,0
access_gi_classroom_admin,access.gi.classroom.admin,model_gi_classroom,group_gi_admin,1,1,1,1

access_gi_cours_admin,access.gi.cours.admin,model_gi_cours,group_gi_admin,1,1,1,1
access_gi_cours_etudiant,access.gi.cours.etudiant,model_gi_cours,group_gi_etudiant,1,0,0,0

access_gi_examen_admin,access.gi.examen.admin,model_gi_examen,group_gi_admin,1,1,1,1
access_gi_examen_etudiant,access.gi.examen.etudiant,model_gi_examen,group_gi_etudiant,1,0,0,0

access_gi_actualites_admin,access.gi.actualites.admin,model_gi_actualites,group_gi_admin,1,1,1,1
access_gi_actualites_etudiant,access.gi.actualites.etudiant,model_gi_actualites,group_gi_etudiant,1,0,0,0

access_gi_note_admin,access.gi.note.admin,model_gi_note,group_gi_admin,1,1,1,1
access_gi_note_etudiant,access.gi.note.etudiant,model_gi_note,group_gi_etudiant,1,0,0,0
```

When I login as admin the menu **genie industriel** is visible:

[image]

But when I login as student the menu **genie industriel** is invisible:

[image]

Where is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Your access right code looks good to me. It seems issue in your *menuitem* definition, check what kind a security groups applied.